# Ionic 2 Sqlite Typescript errors

Tags: sqlite, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic2

hi there i am trying out this SQLite example and I am getting these errors https://github.com/TeamClouders/Ionic-2-sqlite-demo,

`Member 'db' implicitly has an 'any' type.`

`Member 'arr' implicitly has an 'any[]' type.`
`Parameter 'tx' implicitly has an 'any' type.`
...
In https://github.com/TeamClouders/Ionic-2-sqlite-demo/blob/master/src/providers/sqlite.ts

Not sure what the issue is?

Cheers

**UPDATE**
thanks @yugantar kumar
i have seemed get the 'members' type set without errors:

```
public text : string = "";
public db:any = null;
public arr : any = [];
```

However I am still getting errors on the Params - not sure how to set the type of the parameters?
e.g

```
.transaction((tx) => {
tx.executeSql('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Todo (id integer primary 
key,todoItem text)');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@roshambo: You didn't define the type of these variables `db, arr, tx` in the code. Define the type of those variables in the code

Comment: thanks @yugantar kumar i have seemed get the 'members' type set without errors: However I am still getting errors on the Params - not sure how to set the type of the parameters?

Comment: @roshambo I didnt get your doubt much, but are you talking about the *tx* for which u can define type as *any*?

Comment: Hi there, I added :any to all parameters. I have no errors now. but I have a white blank screen with no errors

Comment: @roshambo Without having any specifications, It would be tough to think about it. But good to see that problems raised in this question has been resolved now

Comment: @roshambo: It would be good, if you can find out some specific issue, and raise a new question, if that not belongs to this one.
Also, Will be happy to see if you upvote it too! Thanks